# Prove $\int_a^b f(x)dx=(b-a)f\{a+\theta(b-a)\}$ for some $\theta\in(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

> **Assume $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b],$ and that $F'=f$ on $[a,b].$ Using Fundamental theorem of integral calculus, show that $\int_a^b f(x)dx=(b-a)f\{a+\theta(b-a)\}$ holds for some $\theta\in(0,1)$.**

I am using the "Fundamental theorem of integral calculus" as

> Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Riemann integrable function. If $F: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is an antiderivative of $f$, then $$\int_a^b \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = F(b)-F(a).$$

How to use this theorem to show the above?

Comment: It would seem to me that you need to add, that there exists $\theta$ satisfying what you wrote above. It currently seems to imply that for all $\theta \in (0,1)$.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Edited, thanks,

Comment: I assume you meant to ask the question as in my answer. The way you have it is confusing. Please restate.

Comment: @zhw. Restated, as you have suggested. Please check

Comment: Much better.$\,\,$ I'm going to edit your title to make it simpler.

Comment: The statement says that the integral form of the MVT is valid for every Riemann integrable derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem was supposed to be this: Assume $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b],$ and that $F'=f$ on $[a,b].$ Then the conclusion follows as stated.

Proof: Let $I = \int_a^b f.$ Define

$$G(x) = F(x)-\frac{I}{b-a}x,\,\,\,x\in [a,b].$$

Note that $G'(x) = f(x) - \dfrac{I}{b-a}$ on $[a,b].$ Also note $G(b) - G(a) = 0,$ here using the version of the FTC you stated. Thus by the mean value theorem, $G'(c) = 0$ for some $c\in (a,b).$ This implies

$$0=G'(c) = f(c)-\frac{I}{b-a} \, \implies\, I = (b-a)f(c).$$

Since $c,$ like any point in $(a,b),$ can be writen as $a+\theta(b-a)$ for some $\theta \in (0,1),$ we're done.

Comment: G(b)−G(a)=0,  here using the FTC -- please explore

Comment: Just carry through the calculation, using $F(b)-F(a) = \int_a^bf.$

Comment: @user1942348 I added a small bit to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $F$ as you mentioned. What you want to show translates by the Fundamental theorem to:

$F(b)-F(a)=(b-a) \cdot f\big(a+ \theta(b-a)  \big)$

Which again rewrites as:

$\dfrac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}=f\big(a+ \theta(b-a)  \big)$

If you know that $f$ is continuous, then $F$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and it's derivative is $f$ . By Lagrange's theorem there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that:

$\dfrac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}= F'(c)$

But $c$ can be written as $a+\theta(b-a)$, for some $\theta \in (0,1)$.

Comment: But we're not given $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I assumed that this assumption was ommited, since changing $f$ in a finite amount of points does not change the integral.

Comment: But it could destroy the assumption that $f$ has an antiderivative.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur f  is continuous -- is it required?

Comment: I'm not sure, in the formulation I'm familiar with it is.

Comment: @zhw. whether continuity of f essential? 

F is continuous on [a,b], it is differenntiable on (a,b), then one can apply Lagranges' MVT as the solution given by  Keen-ameteur.

Comment: @user1942348 No, it's not essential. Something like $f(x) = 2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x) = (x^2\sin(1/x))'$ shows this.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though you're trying to prove this for Riemann integrable $f$. It's false in that context: Define $f:[0,2]\to\Bbb R$ by $$f(t)=\begin{cases}1&(0\le t<1),\\-1&(1\le  t\le 2).\end{cases}$$Then $\int_0^2 f(t)=0$ although there is no $t$ with $f(t)=0$.

There must be another hypothesis in  the problem that you haven't told us about...

Comment: No more hyp were there other that I have mentioned.

Comment: @user1942348 That's hard to believe. If so then the problem is simply wrong.

Comment: @user1942348 In fact there must be _something_ you haven't stated. I was just guessing that you're given that $f$ is Riemann integrable. You did't  say so. You must be given _something_ about $f$ or the problem makes no sense at all. Exactly what _are_ you given?

Comment: @david-c-ullrich Ok. I understand, thanks, Yes f should be R-integrable.